# 777 permission is not working under directory

Tags: server, permissions

I have created folder in ubuntu 16.04 with following command:

```
sudo mkdir my_folder
```

after some time, I have change this folder permission to 777 as per the requirment with following command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 my_folder
```

now this folder and all files under this folder have 777 permission. but when user upload new file to this folder, then 644 permission apply to the new file.

but I need 777 permission to new file which required by the software. but I have to change new file permission manually each time.

please help me to set permission to 777 for all new files

Comment: "per the requirment" Please explain. 777 is BAD. "but I need 777 permission to new file which required by the software." Please remove that software or tell the person that made it to learn how to code software. FILES at most need 664 unless they are executables than they need 750 but you do NOT want files executable from within a website. You really really really do not.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that your workaround does not work is that permissions are given to newly uploaded files by the process that are uploading these files (e.g: PHP, ASP, FTP, etc) combined with the `umask` value.

You have to use [ACL](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists).

1. Make new file and directories to inherit parent directory's group:

   ```
   chmod g+s /path/to/directory
   ```
2. Then use this to set group default permission to to rwx:

   ```
   setfacl -d -m g::rwx /path/to/directory
   ```

---

Now lets say parent directory's group name is "web", now "web" group will be assigned to all new directories and their permission would be set to 777, files should get 664 I guess.

Remember that setting file permissions to 777 is not a right thing to do. find out what you are doing wrong.